# How do I to calculate percent and round the result?

Tags: c#

I am selling numbers of lottery and to do this I am available 10000 numbers. Now, I want to know the percent of how much number I've already sell. The problem is that I cannot round the result

How do I to do this ?

**Trying**

```
    IList<NumbersLottery> allNumbers = context.AllNumbers.Where(n => n.concurso.id == concurso.id).ToList();
    int totalNumbers = allNumbers.Count; //10000
    int totalSellings = allNumbers.Where(n => n.status == NumbersLotteryStatus.SELL).ToList().Count;        
    int PercentSells =  (totalNumbers / 100) * totalSellings ;
    Debug.Writeline("Percents Sell: " + PercentSells); 
    //output example -> Percents Sell: 1200
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome?  Using an `int` seems a poor choice for a floating-point outcome which a percentage would surely be...

Comment: 1200% sold is more that just a rounding problem...

Comment: The percentage sold should be `(number_sold / total) * 100`